# Using a previously defined command in a loop stops the loop

Tags: macros

I defined a command `\mycommand`, and then I would like to use it in a loop like

```
\newcounter{myc}\setcounter{myc}{0}
\def\myloop#1{
    \loop
        \ifnum \themyc <#1
        \mycommand
        \stepcounter{myc}
    \repeat
}
```

Well, I get no errors, but the loop runs only one time. If instead I remove `\mycommand` and use normal commands of LaTeX, then it works as expected.

What could be the origin of such behaviour?

The complete code is the following.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}


\makeatletter
\def\prunelist#1{%
\expandafter\edef\csname pgfmath@randomlist@#1\endcsname
    {\the\numexpr\csname pgfmath@randomlist@#1\endcsname-1\relax}
\count@\pgfmath@randomtemp
\loop
    \expandafter\let
    \csname pgfmath@randomlist@#1@\the\count@\expandafter\endcsname
    \csname pgfmath@randomlist@#1@\the\numexpr\count@+1\relax\endcsname
    \ifnum\count@<\csname pgfmath@randomlist@#1\endcsname\relax
    \advance\count@\@ne
\repeat}


\def\declareromanlist#1#2#3{
\expandafter\xdef\csname pgfmath@randomlist@#1\endcsname{#3}
\count@#2\relax
\loop
    \expandafter\xdef
    \csname pgfmath@randomlist@#1@\the\count@\endcsname
    {\@roman\count@}
    \ifnum\count@<#3\relax
    \advance\count@\@ne
\repeat}


\makeatother

\pgfmathsetseed{12538}


\begin{document}

\def\texti{one}
\def\textii{two}
\def\textiii{three}

\declareromanlist{mylist}{1}{3}
\newcounter{num}
\setcounter{num}{0}

\newcommand{\mycommand}[1][\random]{
\stepcounter{num}
\pgfmathrandomitem\z{mylist}\edef\random{\z}\prunelist{mylist}
\expandafter\xdef\csname newtext\roman{num}\endcsname
{\expandafter\csname text#1\endcsname}
}


\newcounter{myc}

\def\myloop#1{%
\setcounter{myc}{0}
\loop  \ifnum\themyc <#1 \stepcounter{myc}
%\mycommand
check: \themyc
\repeat
}

\myloop{3}

\end{document}
```

If I comment `\mycommand`, the loops run three times, if I insert \mycommand, just once.

Comment: Please complete the example so that it demonstrates the error. Whether or not you get an error depends entirely on the definition of `\mycommand` and whether it may be executed more than once.

Comment: You probably want `\expandafter\noexpand\csname text#1\endcsname` as replacement text in the `\xdef`.

Comment: I tryed, but still the loop stops!

Comment: this was a cut-and-paste error, I have \loop! :)

Comment: Unrelated to the question but beware ends of lines, you are missing loads of `%` see the version in my answer.

Comment: @user126154 Can you explain your final aim? I have the feeling that it can be obtained in a simpler way.

Comment: mee too: I just wan to do the "classic" random list of exercies (with solutions) from a database

Comment: first, I found how to make random choices without repetitions, then I wanted to use to define exerciceone as a random exercice and so on... but when I try to combine simple "\def" commands with the macro \prunelist I get many strange behaviour

Comment: for instance, if you read the accepted answer, once I put {\mycommand} into braces, then the loop works but the \prunelist macro doesn't

Comment: my database has the form \def\textN{text of exercice} \def\solN{sol of exercice} where N is positive number written in romanic (so \textiv is the text of the fourth exercice of my database)

Comment: I want to choose random from them

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**New Answer**

As the edited question is unrelated to the original...

`\loop` is a simple macro based on one in plain TeX and can not be nested.
Presumably it is used in the pgf code somewhere. Adding a grouping level solves it:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}


\makeatletter
\def\prunelist#1{%
\expandafter\edef\csname pgfmath@randomlist@#1\endcsname
    {\the\numexpr\csname pgfmath@randomlist@#1\endcsname-1\relax}%
\count@\pgfmath@randomtemp 
\loop
\expandafter\let
\csname pgfmath@randomlist@#1@\the\count@\expandafter\endcsname
\csname pgfmath@randomlist@#1@\the\numexpr\count@+1\relax\endcsname
\ifnum\count@<\csname pgfmath@randomlist@#1\endcsname\relax
\advance\count@\@ne
\repeat}


\def\declareromanlist#1#2#3{%
\expandafter\xdef\csname pgfmath@randomlist@#1\endcsname{#3}%
\count@#2\relax
\loop
\expandafter\xdef
\csname pgfmath@randomlist@#1@\the\count@\endcsname
{\@roman\count@}
\ifnum\count@<#3\relax
\advance\count@\@ne
\repeat}
\makeatother 

\pgfmathsetseed{12538}


\begin{document}

\def\texti{one}
\def\textii{two}
\def\textiii{three}

\declareromanlist{mylist}{1}{3}
\newcounter{num}
\setcounter{num}{0}

\newcommand{\mycommand}[1][\random]{%
\stepcounter{num}%
\pgfmathrandomitem\z{mylist}\def\random{\z}\prunelist{mylist}%
\expandafter\xdef\csname newtext\roman{num}\endcsname
{\expandafter\csname text#1\endcsname}%
}


\newcounter{myc}

\def\myloop#1{%
\setcounter{myc}{0}
\loop  \ifnum\themyc <#1 \stepcounter{myc}%
{\mycommand}%
check: \themyc
\repeat
}

\myloop{3}


\end{document}
```

**Original answer**

You are missing `\loop` but then it will make an error or not depending on the definition of the command, this makes no error unless you uncomment the redefinition.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newcounter{myc}\setcounter{myc}{0}

\def\myloop#1{%
\loop
\ifnum \themyc <#1
\mycommand
\stepcounter{myc}%
\repeat
}


\newcommand\mycommand{ [a] }

%\renewcommand\mycommand{\newcommand\zzzz{x}}

\myloop{4}

\end{document}
```

Comment: sure, the "missing" loop was a cut-and-paste error, sorry. In fact, I have \loop in my code! I edited the question

Comment: @user126154 Yes so I saw, which is why questions should always have complete examples that you can test before posting and people can run to reproduce the error. Yours still has two separate fragments rather than anything that can be run/tested.

Comment: I see. I'll try to isolate a runnable part of the code

Comment: @user126154 answer updated.

Comment: oh, nooo!!! now I have another problem: once \mycommand is inlcuded in { } the prunelist does not work (I still have repetitions in random choices)

Comment: if, instead that using it via the loop \myloop, I use three times the command \mycommand, then \prunelist works...

Comment: @user126154 you could probably make it make global defs so it worked inside the group change `edef` to `xdef` and `\expandafter\let` to  `\global\expandafter\let`

Comment: It seems to work! I'm impressed of how many tricks you know!!!

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer to the specific question, but rather to the main problem.

1. You have a database of the form

   ```
   \def\texti{Text for question 1}
   \def\textii{Text for question 2}
   ...
   \def\soli{Text for solution 1}
   \def\solii{Text for solution 2}
   ...
   ```
2. You want to randomly extract some of the questions and relative answers, without repetition

The following macro `\selectrandom` receives as argument the number of questions to extract and builds macros of the form

```
\usetexti
\usetextii
...
\usesoli
\usesolii
...
```

that will expand to the text of selected questions and relative solutions.

In the code you find a part prefixed by

```
%%% Build the database, just for the example
```

that's just for populating the database with mock data. You will of course do `\input{<database>}` for loading the questions and answers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\input{random}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% interface to random.tex
\cs_set_eq:NN \egreg_random_choose:Nnn \setrannum

%%% User level commands

\NewDocumentCommand{\selectrandom}{m}
 {% #1 is the number of choices to make
  \egreg_select_random:n { #1 }
 }

%%% Variables
% The random integer
\int_new:N \l_egreg_random_int

% A sequence for the available numbers
\seq_new:N \g_egreg_available_numbers_seq
% Populate the sequence
\int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { 100 } % the number of available questions and answers
 { \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_egreg_available_numbers_seq { #1 } }

%%% Public functions
\cs_new_protected:Npn \egreg_select_random:n #1
 {
  % repeat the extraction #1 times
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { #1 } { \egreg_select_one_random:n { ##1 } }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \egreg_select_one_random:n #1
 {
  % extract a random number among the available ones
  \egreg_random_choose:Nnn \l_egreg_random_int { 1 } { \seq_count:N \g_egreg_available_numbers_seq }
  % remove the selected number from the list
  \seq_gremove_all:Nf \g_egreg_available_numbers_seq { \int_to_arabic:n { \l_egreg_random_int } }
  % if the selected number is 42 and the current step is 3
  % make \usetextiii equivalent to \textxlii
  % and \usesoliii equivalent to \solxlii
  \tl_set_eq:cc
   { usetext \int_to_roman:n { #1 } }
   { text \int_to_roman:n { \l_egreg_random_int } }
  \tl_set_eq:cc
   { usesol \int_to_roman:n { #1 } }
   { sol \int_to_roman:n { \l_egreg_random_int } }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_gremove_all:Nn { Nf }

%%% Build the database, just for the example
\int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { 100 }
 {
  \tl_set:cn { text \int_to_roman:n { #1 } } { Text~for~question~#1 }
  \tl_set:cn { sol \int_to_roman:n { #1 } } { Text~for~solution~#1 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\selectrandom{10}

\usetexti\par
\usetextii\par
\usetextiii\par
\usetextiv\par
\usetextv\par
\usetextvi\par
\usetextvii\par
\usetextviii\par
\usetextix\par
\usetextx\par

\bigskip

\usesoli\par
\usesolii\par
\usesoliii\par
\usesoliv\par
\usesolv\par
\usesolvi\par
\usesolvii\par
\usesolviii\par
\usesolix\par
\usesolx\par

\end{document}
```

[image]